# Convert an ArrayList to Xml on a file

Tags: java, xml

I have to convert an ArrayList to XML and save it on a file but it continue to give me this error with debugging information:

```
Exception in thread main com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException: No converter available
------Debugging information---------                                
message             : No converter available                                      
type                : istat.ArrayData
converter           : 
com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.SerializableConverter
message[1]          : Unable to make private void 
java.util.ArrayList.readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream) throws 
java.io.IOException,java.lang.ClassNotFoundException accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.util" to unnamed module @ec756bd
converter[1]        : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.ReflectionConverter
message[2]          : Unable to make field protected transient intjava.util.AbstractList.modCount accessible: module java.base does not opens java.util 
to unnamed module @ec756bd

at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.DefaultConverterLookup.lookupConverterForType(DefaultConverterLookup.java:88)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream$1.lookupConverterForType(XStream.java:472)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convertAnother(TreeMarshaller.java:48)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convertAnother(TreeMarshaller.java:43)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.start(TreeMarshaller.java:82)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.marshal(AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.java:37)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.marshal(XStream.java:1243)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.marshal(XStream.java:1232)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.toXML(XStream.java:1205)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.toXML(XStream.java:1192)
at istat.Running.arrayToXML(Running.java:57)
at istat.Running.main(Running.java:73)
```

in particular I have to transform a CSV file into an ArrayList, but my only problem is when I get to the part of converting to XML.
This is the main class:

```
package istat;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream;
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.xml.StaxDriver;

public class Running  {

private ArrayData list;

public ArrayData readFileArray(File f) {
    FileInputStream fis = null;
    InputStreamReader isr = null;
    BufferedReader br = null;
    try {
        fis = new FileInputStream(f.getPath());
        isr = new InputStreamReader(fis);
        br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        list= new ArrayData();
        String line = "";
        while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
            String[] array=line.split(",");
            if(array[0].equals("groupAge")) {
            }
            else {
                if(array.length==3) {
                    Dati d = new Dati(array[0], array[1], array[2]);
                    list.add(d);
                }
            }
        }   
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    
    finally {
        try {
            br.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return list;
}

public void arrayToXML() {
      XStream xstream = new XStream(new StaxDriver());
      String xml =  xstream.toXML(list);
      FileWriter fw = null;
      try {
          fw = new FileWriter(new File("ArrayList.xml"));
          fw.write(xml);
      }catch(Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
   
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Running r = new Running();
    File f = new File("PersonalComputer.csv");
    
    r.readFileArray(f);
    r.arrayToXML();
}
}
```

I use Eclipse IDE with jdk-17_windows-x64_bin, if it is useful.

Comment: Please show `ArrayData` and `Dati` class

Comment: XStream is trying to use reflection to modify a private field of java.util.AbstractList, or at least that’s what the exception seems to indicate.  If so, it is shady, childish hacking.  It was never acceptable program behavior, and it was always destined to fail eventually.  Solution:  use a better library that doesn’t try to hack the inner workings of Java SE.

Comment: A little more investigation reveals that the com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.SerializableConverter class is, in fact, trying to call setAccessible on private fields.  As I said, it was always destined to fail eventually.  It won’t work with versions of Java later than 8.

Comment: I changed eclipse version by downloading an older one and now everything works, thank you @VGR